# A ring in which every non-invertible element is nilpotent

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with an identity element $1$ and with a zero element $0$. We shall say that an element $a\in R$ is a **nilpotent** if there exist a positive integer $m$ such that $a^m=0$. Clearly, every nilpotent element is not invertible.

Is there a characterization of a ring in which every non-invertible element is nilpotent? The rings $\mathbb Z/(p^a)$, where $p$ is a prime, are examples of such rings. Moreover, in such rings, $x$ is invertible if and only if $1-x$ is not invertible.

Comment: Start here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42647/rings-in-which-every-non-unit-is-a-zero-divisor

Comment: Every such ring is a [local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring).

Comment: Are you thinking only of commutative rings?

Comment: Thanks @lhf. But Nilpotency is a stronger requirement. If M is a maximal ideal (assume R is commutative), don't see why  every element of M is nilpotent.

Comment: The ring don't have to be commutative, but if you have a characterization for commutative rings only, I will happy to hear @Joppy.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378206/under-what-conditions-does-a-ring-r-have-the-property-that-every-zero-divisor-is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be a nilpotent element with degree of nilpotency $n$ in $R$, and $r$ be any other element in $R$.

It cannot be that $ar$ is a unit, for if $ar=u$, then $0=a^nr=a^{n-1}u$, but since $a^{n-1}$ is nonzero by assumption, multiplying it by a unit would be nonzero too.  Therefore $ar$ is nilpotent.  It follows that [$1-ar$ is a unit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119904/29335) for any $r$, and by a [well-known characterization of the Jacobson radical](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3682263/29335), $a\in J(R)$.  So $J(R)$ contains all the nilpotent elements, and consisting of nonunits itself, it is a nil ideal, so it is in fact equal to the set of all nilpotent elements.

By another well-known exercise, when the nonunits are closed under addition (as is the case here, the nonunits=nilpotents are closed under addition), $R$ is a local ring.

So the characterization is: $R$ is a local ring with nil Jacobson radical.

For commutative rings the situation is slightly easier, because you get that the nilpotents form an ideal for free.

> Moreover, in such rings,  is invertible if and only if 1− is not invertible.

That isn't true though. For $R=F_3$, $2$ is invertible and so is $1-2=2$.

What *is* true is that at least one of $x$ and $1-x$ is a unit (this is another way to characterize local rings.)

Comment: Thank @rschwieb. Do you know a reference book that address these issues? especally regarding the fact that in a local ring either $1-x$ or $x$ is a unit.

Comment: @boaz That's obvious though: how could they both be nonunits?  If the ring is local so that the nonunits are closed under addition, that would imply $x+(1-x)=1$ is a nonunit.  I couldn't locate an answered post proving the converse (although I really think there is one out there, somewhere) but I put a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140599/29335) at an unanswered version of the question.

Comment: Thanks @rschwieb.