# Prove that $x$ is either zero or a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $x$ be a nilpotent element of a commutative ring $R$.
> Prove that $x$ is either zero or a zero divisor.

My attempt : I got the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912461/a-ring-in-which-every-non-invertible-element-is-nilpotent?noredirect=1&lq=1) but i didn't understand the answer

My proof  :since  $x$ is nilpotent  , so there exist some index $ m$  with $x^m=0.$

if $m=1 $ then $x=0$

if $m\neq 1$ ,then $x\neq 0$ i,e $xx^{m-1}=0$ where $x^{m-1}=0$ but $x\neq 0$

for example  take $x= \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \neq0$ but $x^{m-1}= \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $m-1 >0$

Is my proof is correct or not ?

Comment: Yes, your basic idea is correct. To tidy up slightly, you should make $m$ the *smallest* positive integer st $x^m=0$. Then if $m>1$, you have $xx^{m-1}=0$ but $x,x^{m-1}$ are both $\ne0$.

Comment: i mention $x^{m-1}=0$ @almagest i thinks u misread its

Comment: Sorry almagest, I was writing up the answer and I did not see you wrote it in the comments before me

Comment: @jasmine Taking $x^{m-1}=0$ makes no sense. Then you just have $x\cdot0=0$, which is obviously true.

Comment: oh... my bad thinking , im sorry @almagest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose as you said that $x$ is nilpotent where the index $m$ is the lowest integer for which we have $x^m = 0$.

If $m = 1$ we have as you said $x=0$.

If $m > 1$ then $x \ne 0$ and $x\cdot x^{m-1} = 0$

But at the beginning we supposed $m$ as the lowest integer for which we have $x^m = 0$, so $x^{m-1} \ne 0$.

Then you can see that the case $m > 1$ lead us to the conclusion that $x$ is a zero-divisor.

Comment: Re your comment below Q - no reason to apologise. Putting up correct answers is always a good idea. People who put answers in comments usually do so because they are in a hurry, don't want to take the time to check carefully, and don't want to risk a downvote. We need correct answers so that the Q gets cleared!

Comment: If you first handle the case $m=1$, it’s still possible that $m=0$. In that case, $R$ has only one element $1_R=0_R$. So the two cases $m=1$ and $m>1$ are not exhaustive.

Comment: Thank you for the approval and the clafirification @almagest, I agree on everything.

Comment: Answering to @SteveKass your sentence is a border phenomena.. Considering the limit case of a commutative ring $R$ with only one element is like consider a single point in $\mathbb{R}$ an interval

Comment: @SteveKass I think some authors define nilpotent elements to be such that $x^m = 0$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$

Comment: @Gabrielek does the fact that we can choose the lowest positive integer for which $x^m = 0$ follow from the Well Ordering Principle (every nonempty set of natural numbers contains a smallest element)?

Comment: Yes, of course.