# A non-zero ring where each element is either invertible or nilpotent, then the ring is local ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to show that a ring in which every element is either a unit or nilpotent is a local ring

To prove this, I will show that the set of non-units form an ideal.
If $n \in \mathfrak{m}$, then for any $r \in R$, I have to show that $rn, nr \in \mathfrak{m}$
If not then $rn, nr$ are invertible. Hence there exist elements $c,d \in R$ such that $crn=nrd=1$. Now note that $$(ncr)(ncr)=n(crn)cr=ncr$$
and
$$(rdn)(rdn)=rd(nrd)n=rdn$$

Thus the elements $ncr, rdn$ are idempotents.

Now if $e$ is an idempotent, then $e(1-e)=0$. Here either $e$ is invertible then $(1-e)=0 \Rightarrow e=1$ else $e$ is nilpotent. Then $e=e^2=e^3= \dots e^k=0$ and hence $e=0$.

Thus $ncr=0,1$ but none of them are $0$ because $1=(crn)(crn)=cr(ncr)n$ and hence $ncr=1$ and we do the same for $nrd$

Hence $n$ is invertible leading to contradiction.

Is is correct way to show that the subset $\mathfrak{m}$ is closed under multiplication with elements of $R$?

Comment: The nilpotents are an ideal $I$ and any element not in $I$ is a unit.

Comment: This is a very popular result in this area, and it will certainly be helpful to have a look at the posts about it. For example, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912461/a-ring-in-which-every-non-invertible-element-is-nilpotent).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Okay. I will surely have a look at that but is my solution correct?

Comment: @reuns, I am not working in a commutative setting. Is it still truem

Comment: @permutation_matrix The proof at the linked question is valid for noncommutative rings. Did you read it?

Comment: @rschwieb, I did read that. Its clear that it is valid for non-commutative rings too. But my question was to reuns where he mentioned that the set of nilpotents forms an ideal and any element not in $I$ is a unit. I am not sure why he wrote that. Even if he has written, I am not sure if it is correct in non-commutative setting.

Comment: @rschwieb, The linked post has an easier solution but my method is also correct I guess?

Comment: @permutation_matrix yes, your idea works… but the “hard part” is showing the sum of non invertible elements is non invertible.

Comment: @rschwieb, I got that sum of non-invertible is so. For me this was the difficult one. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @rschwieb, I saw that the linked post is using another method. That was nice

Comment: @permutation_matrix Yes, you don't need to full weight of "local" to prove the multiplicative part, only the part that says "There are only two idempotents."